# Show hidden files in OSX terminal permanent

Tags: macos, terminal

This should be an easy google but I can't ******* find it.
When I use the `ls` command on a directory I always want to show the hidden files. So basically `ls -a` but I don't want to type the `-a` everytime.

All I find is the `-a` solution, or things about the finder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add an alias to your `~/.bash_aliases` file. Something like `alias la="ls -a"` would work.

Then you can call `$> la` on your command line after running `source ~/.bash_aliases` to show all files, incl. hidden ones.